# Given $F(x,y,z) = \langle\,2xy, x^2 + z, y\,\rangle$ be a conservative vector field. What would the potential function of $F$ be?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I know that a conservative vector field means that the field vector, $F$, is equal to $\nabla\,f.$

So this means that $\nabla$f would be the potential function of $F$ if I'm correct.

So I tried to take the partial derivative of each component with respect to $x, y$ and $z$ and got:

$\nabla$f = $\langle\,2y, 0, 0\,\rangle$

I believe I messed up in the above step but have no idea how to get the answer from this.

The options for the answers are:

i) $x^2 yz$

ii) $x^2 y + yz - 87$

iii) $x^6 yz$

iv) $x^2 y +yz + z$

v) $\langle\,x^2 y, yz, z\,\rangle$

Comment: What I did above was incorrect.. So i found the integrals with respect to x,y,z for each component and obtained: x^2y + y(x^2+z) + yz + constant. This is similar to option ii) but it's missing y(x^2+z), how come this term wasn't included?

Comment: You can’t simply integrate each component of a vector field and then add them up to compute a scalar potential. Observe that the partial derivative w.r. $x$ of the function you obtained is $4xy$, not $2xy$, so it’s clearly incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Your second sentence is wrong: $f$ would be the potential function, not $\nabla f$.

So you need to ask "Is there a function $f$ whose partial derivative with respect to $x$ is $2xy$, and whose partial with respect to $y$ is $x^2 + z$, and whose partial with respect to $z$ is $y$?" Better still, your multiple choice options give you just five things to try as candidates for $f$!

Comment: I attempted this and after integration I got x^2y, (x^2+z)y, and yz for the three components by integrating with respect to x, y and z, respectively. None of these match the options though

Comment: @Mathguy Why are you integrating anything? Since you’ve been given several candidates for $f$ (one of two of which you can discard immediately), simply compute $\nabla f$ for each one and see which one produces $F$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can compute the gradients of the options. Alternatively, if $F = \nabla f$, then you want to solve $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2xy, \quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = x^2+z, \quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = y.$$The condition ${\rm curl}\,F = \vec{0}$ is a necessary condition for the above system having a solution. Since the domain of $F$ is simply-connected, this condition is also sufficient.

Comment: So we integrate say for the first component you wrote, 2xy with respect to x? and etc for the other two for y and z?

Comment: Yes. But the constant of integration will be a function of the variables left off. As in $f(x,y,z) = x^2y + c_1(y,z)$. Now differentiate in $y$ and compare with the second equation to find out $\partial c_1/\partial y$. And so on.

Comment: Hmm, I integrated each component with respect to x,y,z and obtained:
x^2 y + y(x^2 +z) + yz

Comment: @Mathguy No. You start by integrating, say, $2xy$ w/r $x$, which gives $x^2y+g(y,z)$ for some as-yet-unknown function $g$ that doesn’t depend on $x$. Differentiate that w/r $y$ and compare to $x^2+z$ to get $g_y(y,z)$, integrate that, &c. However, none of that is necessary for this problem since you can easily compute the gradient of each of the possible answers and see which one works.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeking the function $f$ for which $\nabla f = F$ (this is the 3-dimensional analogue of an antiderivative for vector fields).  So you want to assume that $$f_x = 2xy \quad\quad f_y = x^2+z \quad\quad f_z = y$$ and then integrate each to find what $f$ should be.  This should get you started toward the solution.

Comment: Integrate each with respect to its component? so for fx, integrate wrt x?